# ActionFilterAttribute .net core WebApi. Set custom response header

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

try varios methods, not sucess.
I want to change the header and get it in javascript

[image]

Result debug, headers.Add 
headers unknown = my header Authorization

[image]

I can not get it in javascript, because he did not send the header, how to send the header?

.net core web api 2.0

Answer (score 0):

solved!

```
solved! // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
        app.UseCors(b => b.AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("Authorization").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
        app.UseMvc();

    }
```

add .WithExposedHeaders("Authorization")

thx